# Changes in UV editor not updating in viewport

Tags: uv

I am hoping this is pretty straight forward. I've searched around and nothing has solved the issue for me yet.

I am making a simple indoor scene. The walls have a baseboard which I have UV unwrapped. I assigned a wood material to the baseboard. In the material preview some of the woodgrains are rotated.

[image: Screen capture]

I'd like to rotate the wood grain for the vertical baseboards but not the horizontal ones. Using a texture coordinate / map seems to rotate the texture for everything. I assumed that I could rotate the individual islands for each baseboard in the UV map, but no changes I make in the UV map (rotation, scale etc) work, it just stays the same.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the "texture coordinate" node set to UV MAP?

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

<sup>The solution was already given in the comments but just to give this question a proper answer here we go...</sup>

Once you have UV unwrapped the object you can rotate and scale the UV islands in the *UV Editor* to match the desired direction and size for the texture.

To take the UV map into effect you need to tell Blender to use it. This is done in the *Shader Editor* in the node setup.

- if the *Vector* slot of the *[Image Texture](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/textures/image.html)* is left unplugged Blender uses the active UV map of this object if present.
- if you have a *Texture Coordinate* node and a *Mapping* node (for overall scaling of the texture) you need to **connect the *UV Map* slot to the *Vector* slot** as shown in the screenshot. Using the *Object* or *Generated* slots will give you the wrong result. This was the simple mistake in this question.
- if your object has more than one UV map you can use a *UV Map* node to choose the correct UV map.

[image: uv mapping node setup]